# Can't figure out how to fix CSS for 3rd party library element

Tags: javascript, html, css, plotly

I am trying to figure out a way to override an odd default in Plotly.js

If you drill down into the class "title-group" title text for [ploty.js polar scatter example](https://plot.ly/javascript/polar-chart/) then you will see that it has an automatic white text-shadow which is hideous when you use anything but a white background. I would like to be able to nullify that text-shadow, but I can't figure out the css to do it. Can it be done? I was thinking that I could somehow make a div around my plot and force all children elements to use a text-shadow with 0 width and 0 height.

So as of now I have this code:

CSS File:

```
div#polarScatterPlotCSS {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #ff0000 !important;
  color: rgb(0,0,255) !important;
}
```

JSX File:

```
<div id="polarScatterPlotCSS">test
    <div id="polarScatterPlot">abc
    </div>
</div>
```

I can see the style applied to "test" and "abc" and even to the text in the legend of my Polar Scatter Plot, which means the Plotly.js chart is affected. The legend text never had a text-shadow though. The title and axis of the plot have the bizarre default text-shadow and are not being overriden :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the above CSS-based solutions, I'll point out that Plotly.js has an API for controlling this in the `layout` object for polar plots.  This allows you to avoid using `!important`.

```
layout: {
    font: {
        outlineColor: 'transparent'  // or repeat layout.paper_bgcolor here
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you write the same parameter in a new rul and add `!important`(before the semicolon, it will override the original setting.

To just "erase" a setting, it depends on the parameter: In some cases you would write `none !important`(or even _without the `!important`), in others `initial`

in your case it's probably `text.shadow: none;`, and if that's not enough write `text.shadow: none !important;`

Comment: I think I have to use text-shadow and not text.shadow. Also, I am new to css. Does this have to be set via id or class or something else? Currently I still cannot get it to work

Comment: it depends: I was talking about CSS (i.e. the stylesheet), where it's indeed `text-shadow`as I wrote (see also http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp). But if you want to set that via javascript, it might be text.shadow

Comment: I updated my question with some code, hopefully this better explains my issue

Comment: yes, so I would write into the CSS: `#polarScatterPlotCSS { text-shadow: none; }

Answer (score 0):

this did it for me:

```
div#polarScatterPlotCSS > * text {
  text-shadow: none !important;
}
```